# How to resolve python shopify api InvalidURL: nonnumeric port: Error

Tags: python, shopify

I am using shopify api in python first time using sameple code availbe on shopify documentation and getting following error:

File "D:\Users\Ammar\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\http\client.py", line 890, in _get_hostport
raise InvalidURL("nonnumeric port: '%s'" % host[i+1:])

InvalidURL: nonnumeric port: '0132af44c3872fc8e0@khawaja-kaleem-com.myshopify.com'

Python3. Shopify-API

```
import shopify
shop_url = "https://apikey:secretkey@storename.myshopify.com/admin"
shopify.ShopifyResource.set_site(shop_url)
```

Comment: Your API Key and API secret seems to be incorrect

Comment: import shopify
shop_url = "https://3fb7eddfca4e5547c2ab7e46fdbd6c7f:0132afdcb83042b5337144c3872fc8e0@storename.myshopify.com/admin"
shopify.ShopifyResource.set_site(shop_url)
# Create a new product
new_product = shopify.Product()
new_product.title = "Burton Custom Freestyle 151"
new_product.product_type = "Snowboard"
new_product.vendor = "Burton"
new_product.save()

# Update a product
new_product.title = "Burton Custom Freestyle 151 - Python Edition"
new_product.save()

Comment: I have added an answer. Please check!

Answer (score 0):

This is an existing issue in Shopify Python Package. You need to upgrade to **API Version - 5.0.1**. You can find more information about the issue raised here - [Link](https://github.com/Shopify/shopify_python_api/issues/314).

Run **`pip install ShopifyAPI==5.0.1`** to upgrade your local package.

Shopify 5.0.1 Package - [Link](https://pypi.org/project/ShopifyAPI/5.0.1/)

Update (Work Around):

```
#instead of:
shop_url = "https://'API_KEY':'PASSWORD'@SHOP_NAME.myshopify.com/admin"
shopify.ShopifyResource.set_site(shop_url)

#use:
shop_url = "https://SHOP_NAME.myshopify.com/admin"
shopify.ShopifyResource.set_user("API_KEY")
shopify.ShopifyResource.set_password("PASSWORD")
shopify.ShopifyResource.set_site(shop_url)
```

Comment: Brother my ShopifyAPI version is 5.1.0

Answer (score 0):

It's nowhere to be found by simply looking at the docs but I found the response on their own tests [here](https://github.com/Shopify/shopify_python_api/blob/a37762500c4d116137ac4c3822269be178f32164/test/test_helper.py#L10)

They instance their session something like this:

```
shopify.ShopifyResource.site = "https://this-is-my-test-show.myshopify.com/admin/api/unstable"
shopify.ShopifyResource.password = None
shopify.ShopifyResource.user = None
```

I'll definitely be looking more at their tests instead of their docs, it seems pretty bad documented